# NGINX - Regex - Search entire location for non alphanumeric

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following regex in my vhost conf:

```
location ~* ^/!/[^a-zA-Z0-9] {
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host;
}
```

But it only appears to match the first character:

```
# Redirects to https://shouttag.com correctly
https://shouttag.com/!/!pink

# Does not redirect as expected
https://shouttag.com/!/p!nk
```

Variations I have tried:

```
# Assume that $ is unnecessary b/c I don't know what the end of the url may be
location ~* ^/!/[^a-zA-Z0-9]$ {

# Only seems to work when capturing data via group syntax ()
location ~* ^/!/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+ {
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm never seen a double ^ char (unless doing not searches). I tried the suggested regex but does not work, in fact it regressed, in that use case #1 is no longer redirecting properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
location ~ ^/!/[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9].*$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host;
}
```

Comment: Damn no luck... still only working only on first character

Comment: Ok, I'll keep banging on it... Glad I asked, no way I would have ever guessed on that pattern.

Comment: ok so I have just installed nginx using docker on my laptop and tested this rule. This is redirecting all the cases i.e. `/!/!pink` and `/!/pink! etc.`

Comment: Ok thanks, it's entirely possible that I have a conflicting rule elsewhere. Going to accept b/c it answers the OP. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This solution did work, thanks again for the answer, works awesome.

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to add an optional hash after the initial string which is required, but can't get it redirect if non-alpha was detected. Something like: `location ~ ^/!/[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9].*(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ {`

Comment: What URL are you trying to match with an optional slash?

Comment: But `/!/ScavengerHunt/qbZYjb` is already matched by above regex

Comment: Ya yer right, I'll add exception for /, and see what happens.